# Modern Warfare 2 ping counter?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I heard about a Modern Warfare 2 *ping stat* like thingy which you can apparently tweak from the options menu, but I can't find it.  Does anyone know where/what it is?  The tool is supposed to display all the players' pings in much greater detail than the current 4-bar counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\call of duty modern warfare 2\players` there is a file called `config_mp.cfg`. Open it with Notepad/Wordpad. There are two values you must tweak, namely `cg_ScoresPing_Interval` and `cg_ScoresPing_MaxBars`. You have some discretion with the former; the latter should be set to `10`. I use the following:

```
seta cg_ScoresPing_Interval "30"
seta cg_ScoresPing_MaxBars "10"
```

[image]

This is how it works. Where the number of bars shown is >1, the ping lies in the following range:

```
(maxbars-shownbars)*interval to (maxbars-shownbars+1)*interval-1
```

For an interval of 30, this means:

- One bar: >270 ms
- Five bars: 150-179 ms
- Nine bars: 30-59 ms
- Ten bars: 0-29 ms

Knowing this, you may want to assign `cg_ScoresPing_Interval` a lower value.

There are also tools available that purportedly unlock the hidden developer console, with which you can enable a numeric ping display. Personally I wouldn't trust programs of this nature because of the small risk that they may be malicious or result in a VAC ban. With that said, you can read about one [here](http://gamerlimit.com/2009/11/hacking-modern-warfare-2-show-ping-numbers-instead-of-bars/).

Comment: Actually, according to Steam regulations, if your 'hack' affects everyone on the server in the same way it's not considered to be a bannable offense.  IE: low-grav mods etc are not VAC-Banned, even though IWnet technically doesn't allow them.

Comment: @Mechko
I know that's what they claim, but there have been false positives in the past (e.g. X-Spectate) and it's not worth the risk for me.

Comment: @Lee yeah that's true.  I just find people willing to risk it and add them on steam.  That way if I feel like playing mods, I can do it without the danger of being banned.  I do appreciate the guys who tell you what mods are running.  I hate being insta-prestiged.  It takes away the sense of achievement.